# How to reverse an order in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I downloaded a Flutter project and In my Home page, I have a dropdown filter bar and the option that I have is only "Latest" for now. I want to implement another option called "Oldest" so that it'll list all my posts from oldest to newest but I'm not really sure how to do that with existing code so I'll be really appreciate if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
                                                                          title: new Text(
                                                                              'Latest',
                                                                              style: TextStyle(color: color.state == 'dark' ? Color(0xFFE9E9E9) : Colors.black)),
                                                                          onTap:
                                                                              () {
                                                                            filter.value =
                                                                                {
                                                                              "id": 0,
                                                                              "name": "Latest",
                                                                            };
                                                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                                                            getPosts();
                                                                          },
```

````
    void getPosts() async {
      if (offlineMode.state && posts.state.length > 0) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "You are currently in offline mode",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0);

        loading.value = false;
        loadingError.value = true;
      } else {
        try {
          loading.value = true;
          loadingError.value = false;
          isLoadMoreDone.value = false;
          page.value = 1;
          var path = filter.value['id'] == 0
              ? "/posts?_embed&per_page=20&page=" + page.value.toString()
              : '/posts?_embed&per_page=20&page=' +
                  page.value.toString() +
                  '&categories=' +
                  filter.value['id'].toString();
          var response = await Network().simpleGet(path);
          var body = json.decode(response.body);
          loading.value = false;
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            posts.state = body;
            if (filter.value['id'] == 0) {
              latestposts.state = posts.state;
              var box = await Hive.openBox('appBox');
              box.put('posts', json.encode(posts.state));
            }
          } else {
            loadingError.value = true;
          }
          getCategories();
        } catch (e) {
          loading.value = false;
          loadingError.value = true;
          print(e);
        }
      }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use **items** property of DropdownButton, like this

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'Latest';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['Latest', 'Oldest']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Result

[image]